# How to use keypoints from another library to OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, sift

I'm using the [Fast SIFT Image Features Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libsift/), which is incredibly faster than the OpenCV implementation (approx 0.01 sec for keypoints and descriptors computations!).

This is the code about how keypoints+descriptor are created:

```
...
Image image = ReadPGM(stdin);
Keypoint keypts;
keypts = GetKeypoints(image);
```

Where:

```
typedef struct KeypointSt {
    float row, col;             // Subpixel location of keypoint.
    float scale, ori;           // Scale and orientation (range [-PI,PI])
    float descrip[128];     // Vector of descriptor values
    struct KeypointSt *next;    // Pointer to next keypoint in list.
} *Keypoint;
```

`ReadPGM` definition isn't relevant for this question.

So my question is: how can I use `keypts` obtained from the code above in OpenCV?

Comment: If you're going to parse the keypoints from a file, you'll lose all your performance gain...

Comment: You're right, I thought the same. Check out my edited question please.